# Switch caused problems to the network

Tags: networking, switch

I used the [TP-LINK 5-Port 10/100/1000Mbps Desktop Switch](http://www.tp-link.com/no/products/details/cat-42_TL-SG105.html) to replace an old switch and connect some devices in my network. After that, many computers had connectivity problems and in general the network was acting weird! After I unplugged the switch all come back to normal. Does the switch need configuration before, or it is malfunctioning and I have to returned it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me really long time to understand why It was happening that but I finally found it!

I thought I had TL-SG105 but in reality I had TL-SG105**E** which is "smart" switch and by default t was getting the IP 192.168.0.1, which was the same as my router! That's why all this mess..

Once I changed the switch's  IP with a different one, all fixed.

Answer (score 2):

After my experience this is caused by a loopback in the network.
This is not necessarily because of the switch, but can be caused by a bad cable or a bad device plugged into the switch.

This is an unmanaged switch that means you can not configure it. It will learn the ip/mac addresses on the network by itself.

The loops in the network are most often caused by hubs (you just want to get rid of those). What a hub does, it sends all of the data it receives on one port to all other ports. If you connect two ports on a hub together, there will be an infinite loop and I saw this bring down even huge networks.

You should troubleshoot the devices. It might be caused by the switch, it might be caused by a bad cable, and might be caused by any devices connected to the switch.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I replaced an old switch, with the new one. When I put the old one again the problem solved. Is this means that the cables are fine and the switch has the problem?

Comment: @yaylitzis - no, you can not be 100% sure. It is possible that the old one can shut down ports if it recognizes a looping issue, or it might have a better processor that can handle it better but will also cause latency in the network. If only the switch is connected to the network and you experience the issue, you can be sure that it is causing the problem. When you experience the lag, unplug cables one by one and check if it is gone. This is the only way you can narrow down the possibilities to find out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a network congestion or cable looping issue on your work. To find this, remove all network cables from the switch, and put one by one. Then find on each computer, is there any weird behavior, slowness etc.

Also check with a spare switch, the same issue happens in a network, there must be problem in system's side NIC also.

This is L2 level switch, no configuration required for each port, and will work as plug and play.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I replaced an old switch, with the new one. When I put the old one again the problem solved. Is this means that the cables are fine and the switch has the problem?

Comment: Entire switch controller or any one of physical port may be the problem. To find out the exactly connect each pc one by one and check the weird issue port by port. Sometime traffic happening through a particular port started the issue, or even the controller ( for all ports ) hangs when traffic happens through the ports.